# Retrieving all living people from wikipedia/wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata, wikidata-api, pywikibot

I have the following query from the WikiData query builder to fetch people, but I would like to fetch only people who are alive. I've tried playing around with date of death but I can't get anything that seems to work, I'm not very familiar with SPARQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P31 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q215627.
    }
    LIMIT 100
  }
}
```

https://query.wikidata.org

I'd optimally want to return the top 50,000 living people sorted by some sort of metric of popularity. If there's a way to do this by API or some other pre-built wrapper around Wikidata I'd appreciate that as well. Thanks!

Comment: `filter not exists` is the way to go - just query for absence of a death date or death place triple

Comment: that said, there is no "popularity" metric in Wikidata - there have been some external datasets computing pagerank on it or on the Wikipedia wikilink structure, but that isn't loaded in Wikidata